# How does Robolectric work? Why does my unit test download some jars while first run Unit Test?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I am going to run a Unit Test in Android Studio, to test my method in ViewModel, I use Robolectric to do this.

Everything works correctly. I found when i run test first time, it downloads some jars automaticly. like `org.robolectric:android-all:jar:5.0.0_r2-robolectric-1`.

So can anybody tell me how does Robolectric download jars, By gradle? or something else? And why does it need these jars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not **gradle**. I think it is just **junit** test runner.

**Robolectric** loads Android dependency on the first run. And it downloads it from maven repository.

**Robolectric** downloads compiled sources of AOSP project to avoid mocking/faking entire Android system